enforce password complexity requirement for bitlocker passwords
I have new disk partition and I am trying to enforce a password complexity for bitlocker but it doesn't seem to work.
What I tried: In group policy editor

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Account Policies -> password policy -> Password must meet complexity requirements (Enabled this)

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> BitLocker Drive Encryption -> Operating System Drives -> Configure use of passwords for operating system drives (Enabled this and in drop down selected require password complexity and under password length selected 8).


Now I right click on the disk partition Turn on Bitlocker, trying to set the password for it.
Case 1: I type 1234567 it says password doesn't meet the length which is GOOD.
Case 2: I type 123456789 it just accepts the password. It doesn't take in the password complexity setting into account. Please help. What happened to the complexity. I see the screenshot and it shows this.

